# BottomAppBar Icons colour not changing when clicked

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-getx

[The image of the result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvYsU.png)

I created a BottomAppBar and I wanted a situation whereby when the icon on the BottomAppBar is clicked, the colour of the Icon changes, and when another Icon is clicked, the first one will go back to default colour set and the current Icon that has been clicked colour will now change. But so far, it's not working, the only time the colour of the icon changes is when i do a hot reload after clicking the icon.

Here is my code.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:get/get_state_manager/src/simple/get_state.dart';
import 'package:unicons/unicons.dart';

import '../../common/constants/colors/colors.dart';
import '../../pages/homepage/controller.dart';

enum BottomBarIcon {
  Home,
  Equalizer,
  Exchange,
  Wallet,
  Ellipsis,
}

class RexBottomBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const RexBottomBar({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<HomeScreenController>(
      builder: (controller) {
        return BottomAppBar(
          color: Color(0xFF121212),
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 80.h, // Increased height to accommodate the text
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                buildBottomBarItem(
                  icon: Icons.home_outlined,
                  text: 'Home',
                  isSelected: controller.selectedIconIndex.value == 0,
                  onTap: () => controller.setSelectedIcon(0),
                ),
                buildBottomBarItem(
                  icon: Icons.equalizer_sharp,
                  text: 'Markets',
                  isSelected: controller.selectedIconIndex.value == 1,
                  onTap: () => controller.setSelectedIcon(1),
                ),
                buildBottomBarItem(
                  icon: UniconsLine.exchange_alt,
                  text: 'Trade',
                  isSelected: controller.selectedIconIndex.value == 2,
                  onTap: () => controller.setSelectedIcon(2),
                ),
                buildBottomBarItem(
                  icon: UniconsLine.wallet,
                  text: 'Assets',
                  isSelected: controller.selectedIconIndex.value == 3,
                  onTap: () => controller.setSelectedIcon(3),
                ),
                buildBottomBarItem(
                  icon: FontAwesomeIcons.ellipsis,
                  text: 'More',
                  isSelected: controller.selectedIconIndex.value == 4,
                  onTap: () => controller.setSelectedIcon(4),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildBottomBarItem({
    required IconData icon,
    required String text,
    required bool isSelected,
    required VoidCallback onTap,
  }) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Icon(
            icon,
            color:
                isSelected ? AppColor.highlightColor : AppColor.offTextColor2,
            size: 25.sp,
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 5.h),
          Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              color:
                  isSelected ? AppColor.highlightColor : AppColor.offTextColor2,
              fontSize: 11.sp,
              letterSpacing: -0.6
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the controller for the Widget.

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get/get_state_manager/src/simple/get_controllers.dart';

class HomeScreenController extends GetxController{
  // Bottom Bar
  RxInt selectedIconIndex = 0.obs;

  void setSelectedIcon(int index) {
    selectedIconIndex.value = index;
  }
```

I figured it the problem out, just incase anyone runs into this kind of error.

Added an index parameter to the buildBottomBarItem method. This parameter is used to identify the position of the icon in the bottom app bar.

Obtain the HomeScreenController instance using Get.find().

Wrapped the content of buildBottomBarItem with an Obx widget. The Obx widget listens to the selectedIconIndex observable in the controller, and whenever it changes, the content inside the Obx is rebuilt. This ensures that the icon color will update immediately when the selectedIconIndex changes.

Inside the Obx, we determine whether the icon is selected based on the current index and the selectedIconIndex in the controller. If they match, the isSelected variable is set to true.

Comment: Have you checked that your setSelectedIcon method called?
if not then try to add   init: HomeScreenController(), // Initialize the controller in geviewbuilder widget.

Comment: I figured what went wrong in the code and fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this approach also, wrap your **BottomAppBar** with **Obx** and initialize controller class in your view file.

```
 Obx(() { Return .... }
```

```
HomeScreenController controller = Get.put(HomeScreenController());
```

[image: Click here to check code]